# add and editing row manually in gridcontrol devexpress

Tags: gridview, devexpress, rows, gridcontrol

im using the grid control of devexpress and i wan use it for take info of a new employee in a system the user have the grid with the columns that he need but the grid have a single row for the user put in the info that i add with

`GridView1.AddNewRow()`

`GridView1.OptionsView.NewItemRowPosition = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.NewItemRowPosition.Bottom`

but when i end edit one of the cell the focus go to the next cell but the changes doesnt save

i search in the documentation but only show how to add with a datasource or do it with buttons, basically i want the user fill n columns of the grid but even when i try the properties

AllowAddRow = True

Editable = True

the grid not allow me to edit or add news rows

I really appreciate any suggestion or help

Comment: What is the datasource? DataTable, List, etc

Comment: I have another grid where the information is presented from a DataSet so i want use this second grid for take the info that the user input and insert it on my DB  like a spreedsheet or a table where you fill all the rows that you need